# CSS/.JS issue with random black line on end of <ul> <li> in Megamenu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have almost completed implementing MegaMenu Reloaded in to my website however a random black line appears on the right of the last  item, on most screen resolutions. I have gone through the css sheets for hours trying to find the problem with no results. Which leads me to believe that the problem might lie somewhere in the .js?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sources to code can be found here!

Comment: Can you post a link to your implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have this:

```
.megamenu > li:last-child {
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #242424;
}
```

Remove that shadow and it sorts it.